# Django API call from extern Website via AJAX Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, django, ajax

i am working for the first time with Django Framework. A service provider is using django i can see the data only with an active Cookie on their API Docs.

We received now an API Token to call for the data on the framework.

I am trying to call the data with the Token via AJAX but i receive everytime the same console log "401 (Unauthorized)".

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRFTOKEN': "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    url: 'www.service-provider.url/api/...',


    success: function () {
        console.log("ok");
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

Sorry i'm a beginner at this point and have no idea where to begin with. I've searched for solution on the inet but couldn't find anything that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i got it! Before the token api key there must be "Token ...".

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://my-url.com/api/1.0/?format=json',
        
        headers:{
              "Content-Type": 'application/json',
              "Authorization": 'Token XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
              
        },
        
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    
    });
```